# Как показать прогрессбар прогрузки своей функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x, progress-bar

У меня есть функция с набором команд:

```
def CovidInfo():
    timedate = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d.%m.%Y  %H:%M:%S")
    covid19 = COVID19Py.COVID19(data_source="jhu")
    place = "RU"
    wInfo = covid19.getLatest();
    ruInfo = covid19.getLocationByCountryCode(place)
    ruConf = ruInfo[0]['latest']['confirmed']
    ruDead = ruInfo[0]['latest']['deaths']
    wConf = wInfo['confirmed']
    wDead = wInfo['deaths']
    os.system('cls')
    print(timedate)
    print('\n')
    print('В мире...')
    print(str('Заражено: ') + '{0:,}'.format(wConf).replace(',', ' '))
    print(str('Умерло: ') + '{0:,}'.format(wDead).replace(',', ' '))
    print('\n')
    print('В России...')
    print(str('Заражено: ') + '{0:,}'.format(ruConf).replace(',', ' '))
    print(str('Умерло: ') + '{0:,}'.format(ruDead).replace(',', ' '))
    print('\n')
```

Но дело в том, что она загружается около пяти-десяти секунд. Как правильно добавить прогрессбар, который будет показывать прогресс выполнения функции? Пробовал модули progressbar и tqdm через циклы, но там функция повторялась несколько раз, и прогрессбар показывал, сколько раз она повторялась.

Comment: *показывать прогресс выполнения* - а вы можете сказать в произвольный момент, какая доля загрузилась?

Comment: Тут нет шагов, к которым можно прогресс бар вешать

Comment: @eri
А как понять, к какой команде можно вешать прогресс бар?

Comment: К той, у которой известно когда конец)